# JavaScriptCore and Swift "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test"

Tags: swift, javascriptcore

I can't for the life of me pass a dictionary (in this case containing a SKLabelNode) or any other object to JavaScriptCore in Swift. I've taken this short sample straight out of a "command line tool" template project I just created in Xcode.

```
import Foundation
import JavaScriptCore
import SpriteKit

let context = JSContext()
let label = SKLabelNode(text:"Test")
context.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(["test": label])
```

This throws me an exception:

```
2014-11-16 18:07:47.104 JSCoreTest[10139:193484] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<JSContext 0x1008268d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test.'
```

I am using Xcode 6.1 on Yosemite. Can anyone reproduce my issue and solve it?

UPDATE:

I thought that perhaps it didn't work because I didn't "JSExport" the object, so I tried with this example, but I still get the same error:

```
protocol MyObjExport: JSExport {
    var foo: String! { get }
}

class MyObj: NSObject, MyObjExport {
    var foo: String! { return "bar" }
}


let context = JSContext(virtualMachine: JSVirtualMachine())
context.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(["test": MyObj()])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong method. You want to use `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` from `JSContext` and not `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` from the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol (which `JSContext` does not conform to) i.e. :

```
let context = JSContext()
let label = SKLabelNode(text:"Test")
context.setObject(label, forKeyedSubscript: "test")
```

Comment: Wow, you are a life saver. Thank you. That method must have been the only one I haven't tried.